# What's your favorite forum that combines the passions of Sound Design AND Music Composition?

Tags: composition, community, forum, sound-design

I'm wondering which forum do you prefer that covers both sound design and music composition?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't like to read that kind of forum. Don't get me wrong but I prefer to follow Pros that are skilled in specific area than listen to people who "have some knowledge about this and maybe heard about that". If I have some questions about sound design google always sends me here on SSD, so it's just perfect :)

Oh, I hope it doesn't sound rude.

Answer (score 0):

In a media context?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean in terms of community; perhaps looking for a site similar to Social Sound Design but with an emphasis on music?

Have you tried Tape Op message boards?

Answer (score 0):

hit the books man, and use your common sense...nobody taught others how to do things...plus many of those people are suffering form "the prince" commplex...they are good but they hit the saturation point where their big heads get on their way...as an artist I believe in collaboration, hard work of group of people who are dedicated and believe in making things open-source...If you look at todays music and movie industry, you will see its just the same cliche thing over and over again...why cause, everyone in the business is so blinded with goal of making money and fame, they forget the first reason they got into this field...sad but capitalism is killing every single industry...hence the mainstream genres, which I will not even bring up...plus its up to you if you wanna waste your day laming on internet or reinforce your foundation, by revising what you know, as they say don't take advice from someone who doesn't have it...do more with less.